# Print button occurs on actual hardcopy in java

Tags: java, swing, button, printing

I am printing various elements such as text and images using the Panels and components it is generating pages for printing and print is also coming but the hard print also has the print button on physical paper. I to remove the print button from the page. here is the code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.print.*;

public class Printing extends JFrame
                          implements ActionListener {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
   // intialise

  }

  public Printing(String Firstname,String LastName,String contactid) 
  {
    super("Print badge");
    WindowUtilities.setNativeLookAndFeel();
    addWindowListener(new ExitListener());
    Container content = getContentPane();
    JButton printButton = new JButton("Print");
    printButton.addActionListener(this);
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    buttonPanel.add(printButton);
    content.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(Firstname,LastName,contactid);
    content.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
  {
        //call for printing


  }
}
```

and code for actual printing panel

```
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel 
{
  private int fontSize1 = 32;

  private Image img1=null;


  public DrawingPanel(String n1,String n2,String n3) 
  {

    String path="D:"+"\\25175.jpg";



    setBackground(Color.white);
    Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 32);
    setFont(font);

    img1=new ImageIcon(path).getImage();


    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
  {

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

    g2d.translate(x, y);
    g2d.setPaint(Color.lightGray);
    AffineTransform origTransform = g2d.getTransform();
    g2d.shear(-0.95, 0);
    g2d.scale(1, 3);

    g2d.setTransform(origTransform);
    g2d.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
    g2d.drawString(string,25 , 50);
    g2d.drawString(string, 125,100);
    g.drawImage(img1, 280, 190, null);
  }
}
```

The print method setup is here

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.print.*;

public class PrintUtilities implements Printable {
  private Component componentToBePrinted;

  public static void printComponent(Component c) {
    new PrintUtilities(c).print();
  }

  public PrintUtilities(Component componentToBePrinted) {
    this.componentToBePrinted = componentToBePrinted;
  }



  public void print() {
    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    printJob.setPrintable(this);
    if (printJob.printDialog())
      try {
        printJob.print();
      } catch(PrinterException e) {
        System.out.println("Error printing: " + e);
      }
  }

  public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) {
    if (pageIndex > 0) {
      return(NO_SUCH_PAGE);
    } else {
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
      g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());

      disableDoubleBuffering(componentToBePrinted);
      componentToBePrinted.paint(g2d);
      enableDoubleBuffering(componentToBePrinted);
      return(PAGE_EXISTS);
    }
  }

  public static void disableDoubleBuffering(Component c) {
    RepaintManager currentManager = RepaintManager.currentManager(c);
    currentManager.setDoubleBufferingEnabled(false);
  }

  public static void enableDoubleBuffering(Component c) {
    RepaintManager currentManager = RepaintManager.currentManager(c);
    currentManager.setDoubleBufferingEnabled(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have left out all the important printing stuff that might have shown us why you seem to be getting the content pane of the frame printed and not just our draw panel...

Comment: i have added the code for print setup and method for printing

Comment: So which component do you actually send to this class?

Comment: by this call PrintUtilities.printComponent(this) in button action listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> by this call PrintUtilities.printComponent(this) in button action listener

This would seem to be your problem.

This will, technically, print the contents of the entire frame, you only need to print the `DrawingPanel`.

This is going to require you to make some minor changes to your code so you access the instance of the `DrawingPanel` from your `actionPerformed` method...

```
private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
public Printing(String Firstname,String LastName,String contactid) 
{
    super("Print badge");
    //...
    drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(Firstname,LastName,contactid);
    //...
}
```

This should no allow you to do something like...

```
PrintUtilities.printComponent(drawingPanel);
```

Instead...

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. define custom clip for the print Graphics to exclude the print button area

OR  2. just hide the button

OR 3. override the button's paintComponent() method where check isPrint flag (if it's false call super it true do nothing).